# Cyclic Reduction Example for Systems of Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I'm doing a research on the Cyclic Reduction method for solving large systems of equations: https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gander/papers/cyclic.pdf

Does anyone know where can I find a concrete example of the method being applied step by step?

Comment: What is it that you actually need? Which parts of the algorithm are unclear?

Comment: Just a concrete example with a given matrix. Can't find one anywhere.

Comment: This is not something that you are likely to find anywhere. You can expect elementary algorithms such as substitution to be illustrated with small examples in many textbooks. But beyond a certain threshold of complexity readers are simply expected to be able to generate such examples directly from the abstract algorithm. The cyclic reduction algorithm falls in this category.  My advice is that you sit down with Gander's description and do a small example with $n=7$ in MATLAB. It is small enough to be manageable and large enough to have the complexity of the general case.